# Non-negative solution to linear equation in $n$ variables

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, linear-algebra

Given a **positive integer** `y` and `n` **positive integers** x<sub>1</sub> , x<sub>2</sub> , ... , x<sub>n</sub> does there exist **non negative integers** a<sub>1</sub> , a<sub>2</sub> , ... , a<sub>n</sub> such that:

$$y = a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \dots + a_n x_n$$

The problem is just to answer if such a<sub>i</sub>'s **exist or not**.

> My approach was to check for a given `y` if either of (y - x<sub>i</sub>) for ***i*** in **[1..n]** is expressible as a linear combination of x<sub>i</sub>'s recursively and base case being that all x<sub>i</sub>'s are expressible. But this approach is too slow for **large** values of y.

Is there some alternate faster approach?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  It sounds like you're asking "what is the condition under which $a_i$'s exist?", and that is a pure math problem, so off-topic here -- but potentially on-topic over at Math.SE.  I'll migrate your question over there.  P.S. It's not clear what $x$ represents in your approach; I don't see an $x$ in the problem statement.  Did you mean $y$ instead of $x$?

Comment: Yes, either the conditions for `y` under which $a_i$'s exist or `y`'s which can be expressed as a linear combination of $x_i$'s with non negative coefficients. I have edited my approach statement to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved using concepts of dijkstra algorithm and number theory.

If we know smallest reachable number $X$ such that $X$ $mod$ x$_i$ = $rem$, then you can reach all larger numbers with such remainder $modulo$ x$_i$ as well, by simply adding x$_i$ one or more times.

The complete description of the algorithm can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVrN_182CfA).

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the subset sum problem, which happens to be NP-Complete. It's also related to the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which, given your problem statement, seems to fit quite nicely.

As the Knapsack problem maximizes the value subjected to a weight constraint, you can apply it giving as maximum weight $y$, and taking for each $x_i$, $v_i = x_i$ as value and $w_i = x_i$ as it's weight.

I'm pretty sure there's a simpler algorithm, but I can't remember it.

There is in fact a dynamic programming algorithm to solve the unbounded Knapsack Problem. In [Rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/Unbounded) you can find the algorithm implemented in a great variety of languages.

Comment: Why would you suggest taking different weights for different values of $x_i$'s. Wouldn't they all have equal weights (say 1) as we have no preferences on choosing either of $x_i$'s. We are not looking for minimizing the coefficients $a_i$'s.

Comment: @user6370652 because the Knapsack algorithm maximizes the total value while keeping the weight under a constraint. To apply the algorith to the sum, your $y$ is the weight constraint and also the target value you'd like the algorithm to output. By setting each $x_i$'s value and weght to $x_i$, you force the algorithm to give you the maximum sum less than or equal to $y$. If the final total value is less than $y$, then it doesn't exist a linear combination of the $x_i$ (with integral coeffiecients $a_i$) which sums $y$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the Knapsack Problem.  It is NP-complete, so you won't find a polynomial-time algorithm.  The dynamical programming algorithm is pseudo-polynomial-time: polynomial in $n$ and $y$, but not in the size of the input (which would be $n \log(y)$).  There are also good heuristic methods that may have a high probability of obtaining a solution when there is one.